# Creating and uploading to a folder in the workfront-api

Tags: attask, workfront-api

Is it possible when uploading a document to a task using the workfront-api to create a folder and assign the document to that folder.
If so is there any guide or documentation on how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create the folder first so that you obtain a folderID to use in the uploading of the document.

Your first call to add the folder would be

```
POST attask/api/v5.0/docfdr?name=NAME_OF_FOLDER&userID=USER_ID_OF_FOLDER_OWNER
```

then you would get your document Handle through the upload process

then you would attach the document using the handle with the following call

```
POST /attask/api/v5.0/document?name=NAME_OF_FILE&handle=HANDLE&docObjCode=USER&objID=OBJECT_ID&folderIDs=FOLDER_ID
```